# Is there a way to get OS X to start a VPN connection before allowing network traffic?

Tags: firewalls, vpn, macos

I'm running OS X 10.8 and have Tunnelblick set up so I can connect to my OpenVPN server at home. I've also used this at $WORK in the past.

When I'm out and about and want to jump on a public network, I'd like to prevent any network traffic before the VPN is connected.

However, when connected to known "safe" networks, connections should be allowed without a VPN connection.

I think I can accomplish most of this with pre/post connect scripts in Tunnelblick, but that only works when the VPN connection is initiated. I need to hook in to the OS to have it automatically disable the blocks when connected to a whitelist of networks...

Any ideas?

Comment: You can use `ipfw` and allow connections only from/to `127.0.0.1` and the IP address of your VPN provider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what I'm using [Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) for.

You can set up different profiles, so for instance you can create a profile for untrusted networks that only allows VPN traffic and is selected by default for unknown networks. Once the VPN connection is set up Little Snitch can automatically switch to a profile for trusted networks, allowing all traffic.

Of course you can create as many profiles as you want, allowing or denying any traffic you wish.